# Defining static const variable in html

Tags: html

I want to define const variable in HTML such as:

```
var ROOT = "C:\\images"
```

and use this variable as `img src like: src="<% ROOT %>\2014\load.jpg"`

how should I do?

Comment: HTML doesn’t know the concept of “variables”. What you have shown, is what templating languages are used for.

Answer (score 1):

If `ROOT` is a dynamic variable that will change depending on time, you're presumably using a server-side language. Each one will have its own syntax for using a variable like that.

However, if you're just using it to save time as you type the page, you could always type `<% ROOT %>` and then <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> before you save.

Obviously there are faster ways, depending on your toolset.

Comment: no, i just made a local html file and use a winform application's webbrowser to show this.